# rxJava, синхронизировать несколько потоков с потоком триггером

Tags: rxjava

Есть несколько обсерверов http запросов, запускающихся при старте приложения параллельно, порождающие некоторый поток сущностей для дальнейшей обработки(doSomething). Допустим request1, request2, request3

Есть один обсервер, запускающийся так-же при старте приложения параллельно с этими запросами, порождающий только onComplete. Допустим init

Надо сделать так, что бы для этих трех потоков doSomething начал работать как только init вернул onComplete.

При этом любой из request'ов может дойти до этапа обработки как раньше, так и позже отработки onComplete.

Сейчас я для этого в init наворотил жуткую конструкцию с булевым флагом готовности такого вида:

```
Observer<Boolean> init = Observer.just(null)
.repeatWhen(o->o.delay(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS))
.map(o->isready).filter(o->o).take(1);
```

и для каждого request склеил такое

```
Observable.concat(init, requestN).skip(1).doSomething(...).subscribe();
```

Но вот чувствую, что это сродни удалению гланд через задний проход. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так...

```
//Класс, выполняющий некие асинхронные действия и сигнализирующий о ходе выполнения
class Worker {
    public static PublishSubject<Boolean> someMethod(){
        //На него будем подписываться. Он одновременно и  Observer и Observable
        PublishSubject<Boolean> trigger = PublishSubject.create();
        //Запускаем что-то асинхронное. Запрос через retrofit с rx например
        Request.api.call()
            .subscribe(
                r->somthing(), //onNext
                e->{trigger.onNext(false);trigger.onComplete()}, //onError. onNext(true) для trigger
                ()->{trigger.onNext(true);trigger.onComplete()} //onComplete. onNext(true) для trigger
            );
        return trigger;
    }
}

//Класс, который будет дергать Worker.someMethod() и асинхронно же ждать от него ответа о выполнении
class SomeClass {
    public void method() {
        Subscription someWork = Worker.someMethod().subscribe(result->doSomthing(result));
        ..........
    }
}
```

Собственно таких Worker-ов может быть сколько угодно и склеивать ответы от них можно как того душа пожелает и методы rx позволят